# Can't get value from dropdownbox to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webform wherein the admin will add new records to database. The form has 1 dropdownbox `drpDepartments` and a few textboxes `EmployeeID, Fname, Lname`, etc. I can add a new record but the option chosen from the dropdownbox isn't changing. It's always the first value. Here are tables `tblEmployee` and `tblDepartment`.

[image]
Here's my `Page_Load()` code:

```
            sConn = new SqlConnection(sStr);
            daEmp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", sConn);
            daDep = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblDepartment", sConn);
            dsEmp = new DataSet();
            dsDep = new DataSet();

            daEmp.Fill(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");
            daDep.Fill(dsDep, "tblDepartment");

            dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Columns["EmployeeID"] };

            drpDepartments.DataSource = dsDep.Tables["tblDepartment"];
            drpDepartments.DataTextField = "Description";
            drpDepartments.DataValueField = "DeptID";
            drpDepartments.DataBind();
```

And the `btnAdd_Click()` code:

```
       cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(daEmp);

        DataRow dRow = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].NewRow();
        dRow["EmployeeID"] = txtID.Text;
        dRow["Lname"] = txtLname.Text;
        dRow["Fname"] = txtFname.Text;
        dRow["Mname"] = txtMname.Text;
        dRow["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
        dRow["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
        dRow["Phone"] = Convert.ToInt64(txtPhone.Text);
        dRow["Jobtitle"] = txtJobtitle.Text;
        dRow["Salary"] = txtSalary.Text;
        dRow["DeptID"] = drpDepartments.SelectedValue;

        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Rows.Add(dRow);
        daEmp.Update(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");
        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].AcceptChanges();

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "test", "<script>alert('New record added!');</script>");
        Refresh();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binding of dropdown must be only in `!IsPostBack`

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 drpDepartments.DataSource = dsDep.Tables["tblDepartment"];// Set DataSource Table First
        drpDepartments.DataTextField = "Department";// Set Column Name of DataTable to set as Text Field
        drpDepartments.DataValueField = "DepartmentID";// Set Column Name of DataTable to set as Value Field
        drpDepartments.DataBind();
}
```

If you bind the DropDownList in postback event, the dropdown will be re-binded in the the button_click (in the page_load) event and the value set by the user will be lost.

Comment: @user2971155 - You indicated that Subin resolved your issue.  Please be so kind as to choose his answer so he receives credit.  After all that's what we answer guys are here for :)